# PowerShell not recognizing basic commands? the term 'get' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet (error)

Tags: powershell

I am trying to learn how to write PowerShell scripts, I tried just typing a basic get command such as:

`get help get`

and I am getting an error saying "the term 'get' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet.

Pretty much every command I tried typing in gives me a similar error,

I was wondering if someone can advise how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cmdlet is named `Get-Help`. Note the hyphen. In fact, all cmdlets follow that *Verb*-*Noun* structure. And always with a hyphen between both.

Comment: I see, yeah its working now, whats weird is I was trying to learn from a tutorial that wasn't using a hyphen and it seemed to work...

Comment: Then said tutorial has a typo, I guess. `Get Help` cannot work. Not in a default PowerShell install, at least.